# How to use Studio Bot in Android Studio Iguana

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have installed `Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 7` in my mac from the official google developer [site](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2023/10/android-studio-iguana-202321-canary-7.html). I have seen that `Studio Bot` is available outside of US like i.e. India region. I have taken news from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/studio-bot/availability). I followed all the 4 steps mentioned by [Get Started](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/studio-bot#get-started) section, but it didn't work and it giving me this error.

[image]

I travelled a lot in Ireland. So I thought it may be region problem. So I tried to change region in my account from here

1. [See results for a different country](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)
2. [How to change your Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en) It always India on these region by default.

What I am missing in here?

Comment: Im bot even able to find Android Studio BOT, I'm using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1

Answer (score 1):

**Use a VPN.**

In my case, I use ProtonVPN with a free account that let me connect to a free US VPN server.

And it worked perfectly.

Hope this help.
:+1:

Comment: I have download it. but, it can't connect because that service must you have upgrade vpn into vpn plus...

Comment: Hi @MichaelFernando, first, feel free to use any vpn with a free plan (this is not a sponsored comment by proton, jajaja), second, in this case with proton vpn, it provide a free plan that let you connect to a free server in USA, Netherlands & Japan, in my case, connecting for free to any server in USA solve the issue